# Join/Merge external SD with internal SD card?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, external-sd, google-play-music, internal-sd

I have a Samsung device of 8GB with an SD card of additional 32GB.

I'm using many apps that cache data for offline use (mainly [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music)), these apps are not smart enough to determine the 32GB of available space and take advantage of it, but instead claim 'no space'.

I thought perhaps there is a workaround for it by merging the external storage with the internal so the apps 'think' there is 48GB.
I don't use several SD cards which means I'm not gonna switch SDs back and forth any time soon.

Do you know a hack for it? Or any solution to make Google Music store its stuff into all available space wherever it is?

I've read [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1251896) link, but since I'm not so much into Android development, I didn't understand it, can anyone refer me or translate it into a more detailed guide (I'm not a complete noob, but I'm not a hacker).

P.S. My device is rooted.

Comment: Technically possible, by using a software raid (striping of both partitions). However: You cannot pull out the sd card any more, nor can you use usb storage. Such a merge is not feasible, without proper support by Android, so there's a high risk to lose data. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mergin your internal an external SD card, I think its easier to just bind the directories with high data to the external SD card. The idea is to link the folder were Google Music stores the offline cache with the SD card, so it will write it there instead of the internal memory. This is valid for any other app that writes to the internal memory, just follow the steps:

1. Go to Settings > Apps > Running and close Google Music.
2. Open your file manager and go to `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache` and delete all files.
3. Create a folder in your external SD card, for example *MyMusic*
4. Create a file in your internal SD card with the mount options, for example *MusicScript.txt*
5. Insert the following in the file (check the directories path as it might change):
   `mount -o bind /emmc/MusicCache/ /sdcard/Android/data/com.google.Android.music/`
6. Go to Google Play store and install [Script Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.tools.scriptmanager).
7. Open *Script Manager*, grant it root, open the *MusicScript.txt* file you've created and select Open As > Script/Executable.
8. Select *su* and *boot* and hit save.
9. Reboot your phone.
10. Open Google Music and click on *Choose* on device music. You should be able to see the total space available is the same as the space available in the external SD card.

As an alternative, if you have a kernel that supports `init.d` scripts, you can skip steps 6 to 8 by adding the file as executable to `/etc/init.d/`, that way it will be executed at boot.

How to find your internal SD card path:

1. Use [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) and it should display your SD card content once you open it. You can check the SD card path in the toolbar at the top.
2. Use any Terminal (e.g. [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot)) and type `mount` or `mount | grep sdcard`, the command should display the mount point or path of your internal SD card.

Comment: Doesn't look like it worked. Does `emmc` refer to the external card?

Comment: You have to check your phone layout, some phones or android versions reference the internal memory as either `/emmc` or `/sdcard`. You can check this by using any file manager and looking where is mounted your sdcard.

Comment: Nops, that didn't work. I copied the same paths as it appears in the device file browser for both internal and external memory card. How can I verify that script has run? Perhaps some other script instructions? Can you please be more specific in details, I'm not an Android expert at all.

Comment: I've added how to check your internal SD card path to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra details. I still didn't understand what means `ES`, I'd also like to ask what terminal you'd recommend.

Comment: "ES File Explorer" is an app from Google Play (its a file explorer). For console I like "ConnectBot", also found in Google Play.

Comment: Are you [skittles](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1785245)? >:P Anyway, this works great on my S3. Except the path was wrong to me. This is the right one: `/data/data/com.google.android.music/files/`

Comment: I couldn't make the `init.d` to work, can you expand more on this?

Comment: The problem is that SManager starts after GMusic starts caching the music, and internal memory is choking.