# How to create start up scripts using the init.d folder?

Tags: boot, mount, init.d

In [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/39980/5962) answer to a question I asked a while ago, he said it's possible to have a script executed every boot.

I created a file (without extension) that contains the following:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

busybox mount -o bind /emmc/Android/data/com.google.android.music/ /sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/
```

I made sure the target folder exists and saved the file to `/system/etc/init.d`, but in fact it looks like the script isn't executed.

P.S. the script file's properties are: `-rwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: I think the answer is mistaken: “the kernel” never calls anything from any `init.d` directory. There needs to be explicit support from the startup scripts for that. I’d need to look at an actual Android device boot process to say how/where, though, can’t do that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my version of Android (cm11 / LolliKat) there is a 90userinit script in `init.d` that tries to run a script named `/data/local/userinit.sh` if it finds it.

I've not tried this, but naming your script `/data/local/userinit.sh` might do the trick.

[I know it's an old question, but for posterity...]

Answer (score 1):

If you have stock ROM you probably don't have `init.d` support.
Permissions of file located in `init.d` folder should be `755` or `777`.
If you don't have `init.d` support you can use kernel adiutor which have `init.d` emulator

Answer (score 1):

On my CM13 I moved script in `/etc/init.d` with extension `.sh` with `chmod 755`  and turned on the support `init.d` with the help of the application Universal `init.d`